# How to include file with extension SVG in LaTeX(Tex.tex)?

Tags: svg

Is there a way to include svg figures directly into LaTeX?
I have only mySVG.svg file and myTex.tex file.
The big question is how to include this svg into my file with extension tex.
I tried all examples in this forum, but without any results for me.

Important!
I have only .svg and .tex file, not .pdf_tex or my svg in pdf format. Is it possible to generate them with latex syntaxis.

Maybe i need something like this (BUT THIS NOT WORKING FOR ME)

```
 \newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
 \executeiffilenewer{MYSVG.svg}{MYSVG.pdf}%
 {inkscape -z -D --file=MYSVG.svg %
 --export-pdf=MYSVG.pdf --export-latex}%
```

and if this code generate PDF
inside in \begin{document}

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \executeiffilenewer{MYSVG.svg}{MYSVG.pdf}{inkscape -z -D --file=MYSVG.svg --export-pdf=MYSVG.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{MYSVG.pdf}
  \caption{FIRST SVG}
  \label{fig:normal} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you don't have inkscape.  Or that you're on windows and need to add it to your path. If it's neither of these be sure to run pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex so that pdflatex to allow pdflatex to call inkscape. LaTeX CANNOT READ SVG, so you need to convert it somehow, transparently inline using the code you have posted or the SVG package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the svg package. It requires Inkscape and PDFLatex as well.

[SVG package description](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/pub//tex/graphics/svg/svg.pdf)

Comment: I'll keep silent next time or comment under the question.